# Bounded sequence implying convergence of power series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $\{ a_{n} r^{n} \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence and $| x_{1} - x_{0} | < r$.

Show that $\sum a_{n} (x_{1} - x_{0} )^{n}$ converges.

I have no idea where to begin with this. It seems intuitive to use the Weierstrass-M Test but that doesn't seem like it would work.

Comment: Hint: $|a_n(x_1-x_0)^n|<\left|(a_nr^n)\frac{(x_1-x_n)^n}{r^n}\right|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I do not know where the $x_{n}$ term is coming from

Comment: the $x_n$ was a typo, sorry.